# export list of edges coordinates

Tags: python

1. 

- hi, im new to blender. I was wondering if there was a way to use python to print a list of coordinates of edges or save into a text document like this:
- x:(the coordinates of one end of the edge)
- 1
- 2
- 3
- so on
- y:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- z:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- x2: (the coordinates of the other end of the edge)
- 1
- 2
- 3
- y2:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- z2:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- ignore bullet points I'm using them to separate lines

Comment: i got 3 errors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'me' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bm' is not defined

Comment: Please read and follow the instructions  (copy script paste into Text Editor)  _"Make sure you are in Edit mode with the required vertices selected and click "Run Script""_